# I am unable to import java.sql.* package in Eclipse Project

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

[image]

I am able to import other packages like java.io to eclipse but, I am unable to import java.sql to my project in eclipse. What could be the reason?

I don't know how to proceed. I have tried a couple of things, but none of them worked out for me.

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` in the source root? If so, what is its contents?

Answer (score 0):

The [`java.sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/package-summary.html) package is included as part of every implementation of Java SE. There is no need to add JARs to your project for the `java.sql` API.

You *do* need to add a JAR for a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) implementing [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), a driver specific to your database of choice such as MySQL or Postgres.

Usually we include a JDBC driver as a dependency managed by Maven or Gradle. If you are not using a dependency manager, you will need to manually add the JDBC driver.

Given your screenshot, I suspect that either you have installed a JRE rather than a full [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit), or your JDK is somehow corrupted. I suggest you delete your current JRE or JDK and download/install a fresh one. Tip: [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/). Java 17 is the current [long-term support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version.

Also, I suggest you skip the JPA/Jakarta Persistence and the Hibernate until you get the basics of a database engine and database connection working. Make a simple little throwaway project to practice.

If you search Stack Overflow you will find full example apps already written for connecting to a database, creating a table, populating the table, and retrieving from the table. Some were even written by me.

Comment: Possibly the OP has a modular Java project, where the `module-info.java` does not contain a `requires java.sql;` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Can you add sql jar in classpath in :-

Download Jar
[http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqljar.htm]

Adding in classpath
[https://www.janbasktraining.com/community/sql-server/how-to-import-a-jar-file-in-eclipse]

Comment: Thanks for you answer Ankur. I tried adding the java.sql but the issue isnt yet resolved. Can you please refer to the screenshot attached.

Comment: This is not correct, the package `java.sql` is part of the standard Java runtime environment.